# react native xcode error | ld: library not found for -lAppAuth

Tags: xcode, react-native, authentication, mobile, appauth

**i have been struggling with this for almost 2 weeks. here is the error:**

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L-L/Users/carrabre/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/imbue-dvxkstblumxsdqhbfwsepkllnggv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AppAuth'
ld: library not found for -lAppAuth
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

**this happens when building in xcode & from the command line in VSCode. i have tried deleting derived data, reintegrating pods, updating pods, factory resetting my computer, making sure my linker files are set up, build active architecture to yes. i would appreciate any help! here is the [error logs](https://docs.google.com/document/d/119wD9M65G-6_WwGjKD0e21kSPd-xM1mqlvZHhk6I3T8/edit?usp=sharing)**

running xcode Version 12.0.1 (12A7300) & mac OS catalina 10.15.7

Comment: You got any solution?

Comment: Any update on this?!

Comment: I am pretty sure it just went away when i updated to BigSur - can't remember exactly how i solved it

Comment: I have also upgraded to Big Sur. But the problem still persists. I have tried opening .xcworkspace file instead of the .xcodeproj file. I have tried  Everything which is present in link(https://stackoverflow.com/Questions/23539147/xcode-ld-Library-not-found-for-lpods)

Answer (score 1):

This looks like the "double -L" problem I've seen other places. This solution seems to work for a lot of people: https://github.com/react-native-community/upgrade-support/issues/36#issuecomment-611516268, i.e.

Go to the project "Build Settings", find "Library Search Paths", and make sure `$(inherited)` is there. Per the above GitHub, you may need to move it to the top of the list.

Comment: i have inherited present still doesnt work same error.